# ./configure says OpenSSL is missing, but it isn't

Tags: packages, openssl

I'm trying to build this application which uses, among other things, OpenSSL. It has a bootstrap script, followed by ./configure , followed by make. In the ./configure stage, I get:

```
yada yada yada etc.
checking for library containing uuid_generate... -luuid
checking for openssl... no
checking for pcre... no
checking for libxml2... no
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 (precise pangolin).

Notes:

- I'm building MonetDB, but I don't want the question to be about that specifically.
- Yes, I do have the relevant *-dev packages installed. I also made sure the power switch is on and the plug is connected to the socket :-)

Comment: What application are you specifically trying to build?  can you post the results of the whereis openssl command?

Comment: also, does ./configure --help produce any useful messages regarding pointing the build script to the location where openssl exists?

Comment: @Richie086: MonetDB. `configure --help` suggests I might want to set the openssl_LIBS and openssl_CFLAGS... but that didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you have the proper -devel package installed instead of just openssl? Like openssl-devel or libopenssl-devel depending on what your build requires.

Comment: As @Richie086 said, run `configure --help`. You could even `grep` it if there's a lot of output: `configure --help | grep -i ssl`. You *should* see a switch like `--with-ssl=XXX` or `--with-openssl=XXX`.

Comment: @einpoklum - What did you set `openssl_CFLAGS` `openssl_LIBS` to?

Comment: @Breakthrough: OpenSSL wasn't missing.

Comment: @einpoklum I meant to word it as missing dependencies.  Sorry about that, I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I was missing the `libxcrypt-dev` package. I also set the environment variables

```
export openssl_CFLAGS=' '
export openssl_LIBS='-lssl -lcrypto  '
export pcre_CFLAGS=' '
export pcre_LIBS='-lpcre  '
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/"
```

Just to be on the safe side (and to resolve a similar issue with the PCRE library.